# How do I convert this date from a string to datetime in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract datetime from a string in a pandas dataframe.
'Date' below is in string (DK-locale)

| Message | date | DateConverted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| blabla | 9. okt. 2021 11.41 | NaT |
| blabla | 9. okt. 2021 11.38 | NaT |
| blabla | 9. okt. 2021 11.01 | NaT |

My cell in jupyter trying to convert looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("messages.csv", sep=",")
df['DateConverted'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce' ,format='%d. %b. %Y %I.%M'
```

I've tried a few variations on the format, but nothing yields results.
Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: your code works fine if `okt` is `oct` on my system. You might want to make sure that your locale is set-up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'da_DK')
'da_DK'
>>>
>>> df['DateConverted'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d. %b. %Y %I.%M')
>>>
>>> df
  Message                date       DateConverted
0  blabla  9. okt. 2021 11.41 2021-10-09 11:41:00
1  blabla  9. okt. 2021 11.38 2021-10-09 11:38:00
2  blabla  9. okt. 2021 11.01 2021-10-09 11:01:00
>>>
>>> df.dtypes
Message                  object
date                     object
DateConverted    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```